# Dagger 2 doesn't generate classes after project build

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have added the following lines to the gradle file

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.3' // if you use the support libraries
}
```

I create a factory ViewModel

```
class MainViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {

        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return mainViewModel as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name")
    }
}
```

Then I call (naturally with the help of retrofit services)

```
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels { 

        DaggerAppComponent.create().mainViewModelFactory()
    }
```

According to several sources of information, after building the project, I expect an error that the DaggerAppComponent class was not created, after which, I also expect that it is created automatically and I can add it using import. However, this does not happen. What can be wrong?

According to several sources of information, after building the project, I expect an error that the DaggerAppComponent class was not created, after which, I also expect that it is created automatically and I can add it using import. However, this does not happen. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you fixed it by now. For anyone who has the same issue, all I hade to do is to update to version `2.47`

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.47")
kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47")
```

I **think** it's a bug with that version.